# Converting image to matrix values whilst maintaining it's positioning and structure

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to get a sample image to convert to grayscale and then output it's matrix values. Using

```
disp(im)
```

I get the image's matrix values but they aren't aligned correctly and with larger files this is causing an issue. Is there any way to write the matrix values directly to a txt file, whilst maintaining their position.

My current code for it is:

```
clc
close all
im=imread('a.png');
im = double(im)/255;
im = rgb2gray(im);
disp(im)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a true black and white, use `im2bw` ([reference](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html)):

```
clc()
close all;

im = imread('a.png');
im = double(im);
im = im2bw(im);
imshow(im);
```

If you want a grayscale, use `rgb2gray` instead ([reference](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html)):

```
clc()
close all;

im = imread('a.png');
im = double(im);
im = rgb2gray(im);
imshow(im);
```

This is the part of your code that is messing things up:

```
im = double(im) / 255;
```

If you want to write any numerical matrix to a text file, a good tool is the `dlmwrite` function ([reference](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html)):

```
dlmwrite('C:\path\my_text.txt',my_array);
```

By default, the delimiter being used is `,`, but you can change it using the function parameters, for example:

```
dlmwrite('C:\path\my_text.txt',my_array,'delimiter','\t'); % use tabs
```